# Grouped bar chart for the following data?

Tags: python, highcharts

I have a simple data frame:

```
value_df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 9, 'Washington'],
                        [7, 8, 'New York'],
                        [3, 10, 'Chicago']],
                        columns = ["Subscribers' Month", "Customers' Month", "City"])

print(value_df)

Subscriber Month   Customer Month         City
6                  7                      Washington
9                  8                      New York
6                  7                      Chicago
```

I would want to chart this data into a grouped bar chart like:

[image: Grouped chart example]

Several libraries exist like `altair` and `ggplot` and I tried forming this with the `altair` package but I'm having problems setting the y-axis to be a numerical range. What would be the best code to make aa graph like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `pandas` [`plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method on your dataframe:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')    

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

value_df.plot(kind='bar', x='City', sharex=True, ax=ax, rot=0, color=['b','r'])

ax.set_title("Subscribers' month and Customers' month")
ax.set_xlabel("City")
ax.grid(axis="y", color="grey")
ax.set_facecolor("white")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
plt.show()
```

You can also send kwargs to the `matplotlib` object, or return the plot to `ax` and do additional formatting from there if you want it to look exactly like your example.

EDIT: link to docs
EDIT2: matplotlib code

Comment: Works like a charm :) Can you also add code for `matplotlib`? That would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Added some styling that should get you close. You can always look up the `matplotlib` docs or other SO questions if you want more specific changes.